# Does "for...of" loop iteration follow the array order in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, ecmascript-6

Iterating over an array using `for...in` doesn't guarantee order, however ES6 introduces a new construct `for...of`.

My limited testing of implementations of `for...of` indicates that it does iterate in order on array, but is this property guaranteed?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

> Iterating over an array using `for...in` doesn't guarantee order, however ES6 introduces a new construct `for...of`.
>
> My limited testing of implementations of `for...of` indicates that it does iterate in order on array, but is this property guaranteed?

Yes, the order of `for-of` on arrays is guaranteed by the [array iterator definition](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/indexed-collections.html#sec-array-iterator-objects): It will visit the entries in the array in numeric index order (including ones that don't exist, such as those in sparse arrays — or perhaps that should be those *not* in sparse arrays :-) ):

Here's an example:

```js
"use strict";

const a = [];
a[3] = "d";
a[0] = "a";
a.foo = "f";
for (const v of a) {
    console.log(v);
}
```

Output:

```
a
undefined
undefined
d
```

Two things to note above:

1. Even though the array has an enumerable property `foo`, it isn't visited.
2. The array is sparse, and `for-of` **did** visit the two entries that aren't present (at indexes 1 and 2).

`for-in`, however, <s>does **not**</s> *did* not have a guaranteed order in ES2015 (aka "ES6") through ES2019; in ES2020, it follows the same property order (with some caveats) as the order-obeying mechanisms added in ES2015 (`Object.getOwnPropertyNames`, etc.). Consider this example:

```js
"use strict";

const a = [];
a.foo = "f";
a[3] = "d";
a[0] = "a";
a.bar = "b";
for (const key in a) {
    console.log(key);
}
```

In ES2015 through ES2019, it might output

```
0
3
foo
bar
```

or

```
foo
bar
0
3
```

or something else.

As of ES2020 and afterward, though, it is specified to output

```
0
3
foo
bar
```

because it has to visit the *integer index* properties first (properties whose names are strings in standard numeric form) in numeric order, followed by other properties in *creation* order (so, `foo` before `bar`).

(That assumes there are no enumerable properties on `Array.prototype` or `Object.prototype` (by default there aren't). If there were, we'd see them as well, but it's not specified where.)

If you want to loop through an array's *values*, `for-of` is a great tool as of ES2015, alongside the other useful tools such as `Array#forEach` (`forEach` is particularly handy on sparse arrays; it skips the entries that don't exist). `for-in` is rarely a good choice. There's an exhaustive list of options in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript/9329476#9329476).

Answer (score 6):

> My limited testing of implementations of `for...of` indicate it does iterate in order on array, but is this property guaranteed?

Yes. But hunting it down is a littlebit complicated, as `for of` doesn't only iterate arrays (like `for in` does enumerate objects). Instead, it generically iterates all *iterable* objects - in the order that their respective iterator supplies.

In fact arrays are such an iterable, and when getting an iterator from them it will be an iterator that yields all elements of the array in the same order as they can be found in the array. You can read the [spec for `ArrayIterator` objects](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0#sec-array-iterator-objects), they basically work like a `for (var index=0; index<array.length; index++) yield array[index];` loop.

Answer (score 3):

As per ES6 spec for [for..of](http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-for-in-and-for-of-statements)

```
for ( LeftHandSideExpression of AssignmentExpression ) Statement
```

> If LeftHandSideExpression is either an ObjectLiteral or an
>   ArrayLiteral and if the lexical token sequence matched by
>   LeftHandSideExpression can be parsed with no tokens left over using
>   AssignmentPattern as the goal symbol then the following rules are not
>   applied. Instead, the Early Error rules for AssignmentPattern are
>   used.

As per this grammar rule definition a for..of loop will be executed in the lexical order of the tokens when it is an **Array** or **Object** Literal.

Here is a nice blog link by David Walsh http://davidwalsh.name/es6-generators where he has explained with example how a `for..of` loop works using iterators.